# Conditional merging of sublists in a list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have the following list of lists.

```
If last sublist has len>1:

x = [[0], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13], [15], [16, 17, 18]]

expected_output = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13], [15, 16, 17, 18]]

If last sublist has len==1:

x = [[0], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13], [15], [16, 17, 18], [19]]

expected_output = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13], [15, 16, 17, 18], [19]]
```

I'm trying to merge the sublists of length 1 with the next sublist.

If the last sublist length is one, I want to leave it as is.

I tried writing the following code.

```
xt = []
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    if len(x[i]) == 1:
        xt.append(x[i]+x[i+1])
#         del x[i+1]
    if len(x[i])>1:
        xt.append(x[i])
print(xt)
```

Comment: But in both cases, your sub list of length 1 get merged with the next sublist. is that assumption correct ?

Comment: Yes. only if the last sub-list is of length 1, I want to leave it as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
def ref1(l):
    con = 0
    l2 = []
    while con<len(l)-1:
        if len(l[con])==1:
            l2.append(l[con]+l[con+1])
            con +=2
        else:
            l2.append(l[con])
            con+=1
    if len(l[-1])==1:
        l2.append(l[-1])
    print(l2)

ref1([[0], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13], [15], [16, 17, 18]])
# OUTPUT : [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13], [15, 16, 17, 18]]

ref1([[0], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13], [15], [16, 17, 18], [19]])
# OUTPUT : [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13], [15, 16, 17, 18], [19]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Code Analysis

```
xt = []
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    if len(x[i]) == 1:
        xt.append(x[i]+x[i+1])
```

This means you are adding the next sublist before visiting it

```
#         del x[i+1]
    if len(x[i])>1:
        xt.append(x[i])
```

and this doesn't have a history of if the sublist has already been merged.

```
print(xt)
```

**Advice**

- Visit the list the other way around, and check each time if the previous list is of length 1.

OR

- Keep tab of if the previous action was a merge.

**TO OP**

If you need more help, please shout